# How does one create a new R environment from C?

Tags: c, r

I wasn't able to find documentation for this. It looks like the R source code uses `NewEnvironment` and `R_NewHashedEnv`, but neither of those are in the public headers, so it looks like they aren't available for me as a user. What function (or what lines of code) should I be using to generate a new ENVSXP?

Comment: If you allow for C++, I can show you how to do it via Rcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `allocSExp`:

```
/* C code in foo.c */
#include "Rinternals.h"
SEXP foo() {
  SEXP res = allocSExp(ENVSXP);
  return res;
}
```

---

```
> # R code (after running R CMD SHLIB foo.c)
> dyn.load("foo.dll")
> .Call("foo")
<environment: 0x016a4084>
```

Comment: Why not a one-or-two liner using [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline)?  Also, you allocate, don't you need to PROTECT/UNPROTECT?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: sad to say, I don't use inline habitually (F- for me).  I don't call any macros after allocating in this simple example, so there's no possibility of another allocation (and potential GC) before my function exits.  I should have been more explicit about that.

Comment: Clearly a case of my trying too hard. There I was looking for some sort of allocEnv function, when the most basic SEXP allocation was all I needed. [And yes, I added the appropriate yelly macros].

You get bonus points if you can point me to documentation that discusses the use of functions like allocSExp...

Comment: @bk.: sorry, no document. I just looked for 'alloc*' in Rinternals.h.

Comment: Obviously there is no need for PROTECT as there is no allocation *after* the `allocSExp` and (ENVSXP is not an R object)

Comment: The above will only work for a non-hashed environment and creates a little odd environment whose parent is `NULL` (which should only be used for internals). If you want to play really safe I think you can only use `eval(lang1(install("new.env")),env)` or similar. (but I'd still go for the `NewEnv*` functions)

Comment: @SimonUrbanek: you should really take your comments (including those you deleted :) and craft an answer of your own.  You have a lot of wisdom to share and I'd hate for it to be buried in comments.

Answer (score 1):

As of R 4.1.0, you can now use the C function `R_NewEnv()`, which has a signature of:

```c
SEXP R_NewEnv(SEXP enclos, int hash, int size);
```

Where you provide:

- `enclos`: The parent environment
- `hash`: Either 1 or 0 depending on if you want a hashed environment
- `size`: The initial size of the environment (if <= 0, it will use an internal default size, which is currently set to 29)

This takes the same arguments as the R level `new.env()`, but will be a bit faster because you don't need a callback to R.

Here is the commit that introduced it:
https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/8a322e786068ec2e23324e61821ff666d0b6e329